# Using require in nodejs to access external javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, require

I have been trying to use require in nodejs to access javascript files with simple scripts on them. My goal is to require the script and output its return value to the console. So far this is what I have:

```
oper2 = function(){
    var x = 1;
    var y = x+1;
    return y;
};

module.exports = {
   oper2: oper2
};
```

This is the file I would like to access through my nodejs api, in the api I have this code attempting to use require:

```
        var dir = 'files/'+name;
        var func = require('./'+dir);

        console.log("here?");

        console.log("Value" + func.oper2()); //test operation

        res.json('done');//value received by the api
```

I have attempted multiple version of the file and the code to require the file but have not gone very far. It always crashes in the var func = ..... line saying error cannot find module. This is even though I have code before this to test whether or not it reads the file, and it is finding and reading the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

```
files.route('/:name/execute')
    .post(function (req, res){

        var dir = 'files/'+name;
            var func = require('./'+dir);

            console.log("here?");

            console.log("Value " + func.oper2);


            res.json('done');


});
```

At the moment it still crashes when requiring.

edit 3 error being received:

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
            
    at require (module.js:380:17)
                
    at server.use.express.static.index (D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\server.js:613:24)
                    
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
                        
    at next (D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
                            
    at Route.dispatch (D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
                                
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
                                    
    at D:\udu\tcide_a\src\tcide\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22

edit 4(this is my exact code, I just simplified it above):

```
behaviorR.route('/:behavior/execute')
    .get(function (req, res){

        var dir = 'operations/'+req.params.behavior;

        // if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        //     console.log('Not found');;
        // }
        // else{
            console.log('About to require');

            var func = require('./'+dir);

            console.log("here?");

            // console.log("Value %d", func.oper2(5));


            res.json('done');
        // }

        // fs.readFile('operations/'+req.params.behavior+'.js', "utf8", function(error, data) {
        //   res.json(data);
        // });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the function and export it inside an object (without the .js)

```
var oper2 = function(value){
    var x = 1;
    var y = x+1+value;
    return y;
};

// Export object which contains the above method
module.exports = {
   oper2: oper2
};
```

in your main module

```
var dir = 'files/'+name;
var func = require('./'+dir);

console.log("Value %d", func.oper2(5)); //test operation

res.json('done');//value received by the api
```

Comment: I added what you mentioned and it no longer crashes when requiring, although now it does not go beyond that line. Meaning, it never gets to the console.log("here?"); I added right after it.

Comment: Could you please post the entire main file you wish to include the other module in

Comment: I added the method where it is, the entire file is a decently big restful api

Comment: I made a mistake when doing the GET call (had POST activated, hence the reason it was not getting an error), but even with your modifications I am still getting this error, shown in edit 3

Comment: from where you will get `name`'s value?

Comment: i get it through req.params.name I just simplified the code I posted, but the directory is working, as in my actual program I have commented out code in order to check if the file exists and to read it, which it does correctly

Comment: it should works smoothly, weird!

Can you double check the contents of `req.params.behavior` and `dir`

Comment: I have checked it, if I un-comment the part where it reads the file, it will find it and output its contents without any problems using the same variable dir, I have read a good amount of tutorials trying to figure this out and code seems fine but it keeps giving me an error when requiring it

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` is the object returned by require. Using module.exports will allow your required module to be called like function.

```
var oper2 = function(value){
    var x = 1;
    var y = x+1+value;
    return y;
};

module.exports = oper2;
```

And in main file

```
var dir = 'files/'+name;
var func = require('./'+dir);
console.log("Value %d", func(5)); //test operation
res.json('done');//value received by the api
```

Using `exports`  you can add functions and objects to the root of your module.

```
exports.oper2 = function(value){
    var x = 1;
    var y = x+1+value;
    return y;
};
```

And in main file

```
var dir = 'files/'+name;
var func = require('./'+dir);
console.log("Value %d", func.oper2(5)); //test operation
res.json('done');//value received by the api
```

Comment: This gives me the same error, I have edited my question to include the error being given, as well as my exact code, I had previously posted one in a simplified manner